# After node.js failure, set command stopped working on linux

Tags: node.js, terminal, debian

I was trying to integrate Jade into Koala, but I have NEVER used Node.js before. I installed via the command line with apt-get install node, but I got errors whenever I tried to use npm.

I was trying to check the path for NODE_PATH, but when I used the "set" command in the terminal, it seems to cat the set file, as opposed to executing it. At least I think that's what's happening, as I'm somewhat new to linux in general.

Here is the error that NPM is throwing me. It's a local install btw.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: jade 
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-    client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/user/Desktop/koala-jade-master/npm-debug.log        
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/user/Desktop/koala-jade-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: jade
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/Desktop/koala-jade-master/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Here's the log from npm-debug.log

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'jade' ]
info using npm@1.1.4
info using node@v0.6.19
verbose config file /home/user/.npmrc
verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /usr/share/npm/npmrc
verbose cache add [ 'jade', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'jade', [ 'jade', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'jade', path: 'jade', href: 'jade' }
verbose addNamed [ 'jade', '' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'jade', '', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging jade
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './jade' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: jade
ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
ERR! or use
ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/user/npm-debug.log npm
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-35-generic
ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "jade"
ERR! cwd /home/user
ERR! node -v v0.6.19
ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: jade
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: What errors did you get from npm?  If you want to see what NODE_PATH is, say `echo $NODE_PATH`.  I don't think you need the `set` command at all.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've added the NPM error

Comment: OK, so you see how it says "Additional logging details can be found in: /home/user/Desktop/koala-jade-master/npm-debug.log"?  Can you show us that file too?

Comment: @JohnZwinck there you go!